# fetch data from three mysql table

Tags: mysql

I am trying to fetch data from three tables using left join.but i am not able to fetch the correct data.
Here i have three tables login,cart,cart_details now i want data present data with deviceId in all three tables sometime there will be no data in cart_details.

```
SELECT login.deviceId,
       login.userId,
       login.name,
       login.email,
       login.mobile,
       login.userType,
       cart.cartId,
       cart_details.cartDetailsId 
FROM login 
LEFT JOIN cart ON login.deviceId=cart.deviceId 
LEFT JOIN cart_details ON cart.deviceId=cart_details.deviceId 
WHERE mobile='${mobile}' 
  AND password='${password}'
```

what am i doing wrong?

For example

```
login
-----------------
deviceId | name | email | mobile | password                                        
1        | abc  | abc@  | 12346   | abcs
2        | abcd  | abcd@  | 12345   | abcs
```

```
cart
----------------------
deviceId | cartId
1         | 123
2         | 1234
```

```
cart_details
------------------------
deviceId | cartDetailsId
1        | 987
```

So now with above example i would like too fetch data as

```
deviceId,name,email,mobile,cartId,cartDetaisld
1,abc,abc@,1234,123,987
2,abcd,abcd@,12345,1234,''
```

Comment: What tables the columns `mobile` and `password` are taken from? *but i am not able to fetch the correct data* With what incorrectness the data is fetched? Show source data example and desired output.

Comment: mobile and password is taken from login table. I am trying to fetch the data deviceId,name,email,mobile,cartId and cartDetailsId. sometime there will be no cartDetailsId but the mandatory data which i need is deviceId,name,email,mobile,cartId and cartId is from cart table

Comment: Please provide [mre]

Comment: *mobile and password is taken from login table.* If so the query must give correct output/ Provide sample data and show desired output for it.

Comment: i have added the sample data please check

Comment: Let's try again: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is here:

```
WHERE mobile='${mobile}' AND password='${password}'
```

Here is a query that answers your example :

```
select 
  l.deviceId,
  l.name,
  l.email,
  l.mobile,
  c.cartId,
  (case
     when cd.cartDetailsId IS NULL then ''
     else cd.cartDetailsId
   end) as cartDetailsId
from login l
left join cart c
  on c.deviceId = l.deviceId
left join cart_details cd
  on cd.deviceId = l.deviceId
```

you can see it on this link:
[http://sqlfiddle.com/](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6a43a/9)